# Number of monotone boolean functions on Divisors of an integer (multisets)

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders

The Dedekind number is the count of monotone boolean function from $\mathbf{2}^d$ to $\{0,1\}$. Does anyone know any research about its extension, from $[e_1]\times\cdots\times[e_d]$ to $\{0,1\}$? Here $[n]$ means $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Terminology:

A monotone boolean function $f$ is such that $f(x)\geq f(y)$ whenever $x\geq y$, where $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$ for all $x$.

There are two equivalent ways to describe the poset $P$ that $x$ and $y$ live in:

(1) $P=[e_1]\times\cdots\times[e_d]$, where $x\geq y$ if $x_i\geq y_i$ for all $i\in [d]$. Note that $\mathbf{2}^d$ corresponds to $e_1=\cdots=e_d=2$ up to offset.

(2) $P$ is the set of divisors of $N=p_1^{e_1-1}\cdots p_d^{e_d-1}$, where $p_1,\ldots,p_d$ are distinct primes and relation $\geq$ is overwritten by "is a multiple of". That is, the monotone boolean function $f$ should be such that $f(x)\geq f(y)$ if $x$ is divisible by $y$.

Comment: What does "boolean" mean here? What is the defference between "monotone function from $[e_1]\times\cdots\times[e_d]$ to $\{0,1\}$" and "monotone ***boolean*** function from $[e_1]\times\cdots\times[e_d]$ to $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @bof It seems that $e_i$ are arbitrary prime numbers, and not just $2$, so it is not boolean. In that case, Shen-Fu Tsai is searching for some generalization of what he says it's called Dedekind numbers.

Comment: @amrsa Where do you get "prime", I thought the $e_i$ were supposed to be arbitrary natural numbers.

Comment: @bof maybe I misunderstood. By the title, I though that $e_1, \ldots, e_d$ were the prime factors of some integer, but now I think I was wrong.

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion. I edited my post to clarify, let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: You're asking for the number of antichains in a product of chains. The articles on antichains in Wikipedia and MathWorld have numerous references; counting antichains seems to be a hard problem in general.

Comment: I know, that's exactly what I'm asking :)